# MATCH throwing data type error

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a requirement to do a reference lookup based on 2 columns of data.  The formulas show the proper result in the "Function Arguments" dialog but for some reason display `#VALUE!` in the cells.  Below is a simplified example of what is occurring, reference data is shown in rows 2 through 5.

[image]

Index and Match formulas in `C8` through `D12` are throwing value errors (based on the `MATCH`) but if you open the Function Arguments Dialog both show the correct answers being calculated. Each row uses the same basic formula which uses the values from columns A and B to perform a lookup of the Usance Code for the matching row in the reference area.  Formulas for cells `C8` and `D8` are as follows:

C8

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$5,MATCH(A8 & B8, $A$2:$A$5 & $B$2:$B$5, 0), 3)
```

D8

```
=MATCH(A8&B8,$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5,0)
```

The `MATCH` is throwing the error "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type" and displays `#VALUE!` but if you position your cursor in a cell with either formula and select "Insert Function" to open the Function Arguments Dialog the formula is calculating the correct result for both their `INDEX` and `MATCH` formulas as shown above.

If someone could explain the underlying reason for the data type error and provide a solution it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the formula you used is an array formula. `$A$2:$A$5 & $B$2:$B$5` is an array, because the concatenate function (here used in the form of `&`) does not apply to arrays unless explicitly called by the function.

Normal formulae will thus get the error `#VALUE!`.

To go around this issue, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing out the formula instead of only <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That should solve the issue. You'll also notice braces being inserted in the formula (from the formula bar) when you do this, these indicate array formulae.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option here is to use `LOOKUP` function to get the required result - doesn't require "array entry", i.e. this formula in C8 copied down

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A$2:A$5=A8)/(B$2:B$5=B8),C$2:C$5)`

Note that if A8 and B8 both match on more than one row you get the **last** one